# Why I am getting unboundLocalError in below function?

Tags: python, function, variables

```
x=23

def printer():
    
    print(x)

    x=x+1

    return x

printer()
```

**Error:** UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment

Comment: Inside the function you haven't declared x to be global, and therefore Python can't tell if you mean the global variable x or a new local variable also named x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use global keyword to fix the issue

```
def printer():

    global x
    
    print(x)

    x=x+1

    return x
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working. But small doubt here - i have already declared and assigned variable x = 25 before the function, so why do I need use global keyword here? why i can't able to access directly? Is there any rules about this in python? TIA

Comment: Read about python scope - https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp